# How can I use jQuery.each() loop on Array of Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, loops

I have this array of object, how can I loop through it using jQuery.each()?

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [parent_cat_id] => 1
            [child_cat_name] => Java
            [status] => 1
            [date] => 2016-09-11 01:26:00
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [parent_cat_id] => 1
            [child_cat_name] => JavaScript
            [status] => 1
            [date] => 2016-09-11 01:26:00
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 3
            [parent_cat_id] => 1
            [child_cat_name] => HTML
            [status] => 1
            [date] => 2016-09-11 01:26:00
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 4
            [parent_cat_id] => 1
            [child_cat_name] => PHP
            [status] => 1
            [date] => 2016-09-11 01:26:00
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 5
            [parent_cat_id] => 1
            [child_cat_name] => Python
            [status] => 1
            [date] => 2016-09-11 01:26:00
        )

    [5] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 6
            [parent_cat_id] => 1
            [child_cat_name] => Ruby
            [status] => 1
            [date] => 2016-09-11 01:26:00
        )

)
```

I am trying to use this -

```
$.each( data, function( key, value ) {
    console.log( value );
});
```

Which giving me following error -

> TypeError: invalid 'in' operand e

Comment: You show us the dump of a PHP object, can you show us the log of the JS one?

Comment: This is what I get if i do `console.log(data)`

Comment: @Simon then you are not returning json to the client.

Answer (score 8):

Your array has strange formatting. See this example:

```
        var data = [    
            {text: "hello"},
            {text: "good bye"},
            {text: "Hello again"}       
        ]

        $.each( data, function( key, value ) {
            console.log( value.text );
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggested you to use forEach instead. jQuery.each method has another goal.

```
data.forEach(function(entry) {
    //Your logic.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery.each syntax is correct, but As Karl-André Gagnon mentioned, that is the output of a PHP array.

Pass your array through `json_encode` before sending it to the front-end.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: Yes I know I can pass is it using `json_encode`, but I want to keep my data like this so it is suitable for normal php loops.

Comment: @Simon you can't do both.

Comment: @Simon, what I mean is pass it through `json_encode` as you're passing it to the client-side. You don't have to convert it permanently.

Comment: Thank you guys, I will think about it.